# How do I calculate Percentages of Variables

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make a variable go up by a certain percent every time you click a button. I understand how I could do most of that, I just need to know how to multiply variables with percentages.

Could anyone explain to me how to multiply variables with percentages?

```
function gainCoinsPS6MP() {
  if (coins >= Cost6MP) {
    coinsPS += 1;
    coins -= Cost6MP;
    (((Cost6MP = Cost6MP += 10 % of Cost6MP)))
  } else {
    alert("You trying to scam me!?");
  }
```

The stuff in the three brackets is what I need to replace with code to change the price of an object by ten percent every time you by one of them.

Comment: Add the code you already got and tell us where you got stuck, then we can help you better. Are you already familiar with JavaScript?

Comment: It is worth adding more information. For e.g. like are using javascript or any other programming language. Worth adding your code as J.Doe mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You need JavaScript for that:

First create your variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = 0;
</script>
```

and then you can increase your variable by button click:

```
<button onclick="x = x + ((x * 30)/100)">Click to Increment</button>
```

Where `30` is the percent you want to increase `x`

---

**EDIT because of comment:**

I would suggest to write a function:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = 10;
    var y = 20;
    if (x > y) {
        x = x + ((x * 30)/100)
    } else {
      document.write("x is not bigger than y")
    }
}
</script>
```

and then just call the function at button click event:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Check if x bigger than y</button>
```

Comment: Can you add this code to your question for better formatting?

Comment: Could you somehow insert an if command to make sure a certain variable is the right amount. (I want to only change the variable if another variable was higher than it)

Comment: <button button type="button" onclick="gainCoinsPS6MP()"> <img src = "$_35.jpg" alt = "$_35.jpg Image" width="100" height="75">  <img src = "2006 Mac Pro.png" alt = "2006 Mack Pro Image" width="50" height="75">
</button>                                                                                                    
   is it possible for me to link this html buttons "gainCoinsPS6MP()" to the java "my function()" so that my other code linked to the button (that you can see up the top of this page) can still work.